# Containerized database file path and root directory unknown

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis

I recently tried copying my database contents to a csv file with the following command inside my containerized Postgres database:

```
\copy ${TABLE} TO ${FILE} DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I got a response indicating the file was successfully copied however I can't find where it was copied to. When I try specifying a different path to output the file, I get the response `directory/file.csv: No such file or directory`

**Does anyone know where containerized databases output files and how I can direct them to accessible locations?**

I am on a Mac OS and this is some of the relevant info from my docker-compose file with which the database was initiated.

```
  db:
      image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
      volumes:
        - postgis:/var/lib/postgresql
```

Comment: enter the postgresql container and search for the file `find / -iname "file.csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers store their information internally in what is called Docker volumes. You can read more literature on that in [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Regarding your particular issue, you've got some options:

- Copy to a temporary file and pull it from the container:

```sql
\copy ${TABLE} TO /tmp/file.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Then run `docker ps`, find your container ID and run:

```sh
docker cp container_id:/tmp/file.csv file.csv
```

And you will have `file.csv` with the data in your current folder.

- Another, simpler way is to export to stdout, if the output is gonna be short:

```
\copy ${TABLE} TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

This will dump all the data through the terminal. Only use it if there are few enough registers that it doesn't get past the scrollback.

- Third option, because two are never enough... you could publish temporarily the 5432 port and connect from your local machine using `psql`... then running the copy command will dump to your local machine. (Or use third-party tools like pgAdmin or DataGrip to dump the information).

Comment: You're a god-send mate. To anyone else reading this down the line: pay attention to the warnings listed for the second option, if the data set is too large it'll crash your terminal or   editor